# Optimal parametrization in nonlinear least squares

Tags: machine-learning, least-squares, nonlinear-regression, fitting, curve-fitting

First off, I would like to mention that I am by no means a statistician/mathematician, so I hope this question makes sense (my formal background is in physics).

I was wondering about optimal parametrization in nonlinear least squares fitting (as the question title gives away). Basically, if I start with a nonlinear model, $f(\boldsymbol{x};\boldsymbol{\theta})$, is there an optimal way to reparametrize the function, say $\boldsymbol{\theta}\to\boldsymbol{\theta'}$, so that the fit values from the least squares are more precise/accurate?

I know, for example, by diagonalizing the Hessian/Fisher information matrix, one can try (is this always possible?) and rewrite the model in the new orthogonal basis, so that the function only varies along each coordinate. But, of course, this would only solve the problem locally, so that the parametrization would probably have to change simultaneously as the function is being fitted.

Comment: Reparameterization would not change the fit whatsoever.  It only changes the name you give to the function that fits best.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I am asking this question mainly because I have heard people talk about "natural" coordinates, when talking about fitting. I guess I was wondering because I can imagine a parametrization where the search is faster, or something... Anyway, thanks again.

Comment: Whether a search (or other technique to find the minimum) is faster or not is a matter of the algorithm you use and where you start, among other things: but it's a separate issue from accuracy of the fit.  With many techniques, if you can transform the parameter so that (a) the function becomes quadratic near its global minimum and (b) start the search close to that minimum, you can converge on the solution extremely rapidly: potentially in a single step. But that's primarily a theoretical result rather than a practical one.

Comment: For optimality in terns of accuracy, reparameterization should not change the solution, as @whuber notes above. However it is worth noting that reparameterization can make the objective function and/or its derivatives easier/cheaper to evaluate (and the same for any constraints). So under a fixed computational budget, this could perhaps yield a better (partial) solution in some practical cases.

Comment: @GeoMatt Unless the parameterization itself is expensive--and that seems like a rare circumstance--it isn't possible for it to make evaluation of the objective function substantially cheaper.  Proof: to evaluate the function under the new parameterization, convert back to the original parameterization (cheaply) and apply the cheap evaluation there. A similar argument holds for the derivatives.

Comment: I take it $f$ is a density for $x$ and we're doing maximum likelihood? An important and practical distinction is whether $f$ is concave (or [log-concave](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmically_concave_function)) in $\theta$ or not. Generally speaking, [convex problems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_optimization) can be efficiently solved by numerical methods while non-convex problems can have horrible problems with local minima. iI your problem is a convex optimization problem, you want to exploit that (and not have a crappy parameterization that makes the problem non-convex).

Comment: @whuber I did not mean "big O" cheaper :)  (I have had some experiences where formulating for a box-constrained solver gave significant improvements over a general linear-constraint solver ... but the algorithm was not exactly held constant between the two)

Comment: @GeoMatt Nor did I mean anything in a big-O sense.  However, I am implicitly dismissing differences that are of little consequence, such as a few percent.  Just to muddy things even more note, too, that there are two different questions in evidence: one is whether there might be some universal reparameterization of $\theta$ that helps regardless of $x$; the other is whether there might be a method to identify a reparameterization, *dependent on $x$*, that can help.